# How to find all buttons which contains a specific string using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, button, xpath, text

I want to find all buttons on the page which contain the word "card" or the word "bag".

For example it could be "add to card" or "add to bag" or "card" etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.color import Color
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.inshoes.gr/andrikes-zones-andrikes-zones-dermatines-diplis-opseos-33000481-kamel-mavro')
buttons=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Click me!"]')

for button in buttons:
    print (button)
```

Comment: For example it could be "add to card" or "add to bag" or "card" etc. - Which buttons you are looking please specify them.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for this exact use case (for accepting cookies):

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Accept cookies')]") # Try Click Cookies
```

You can interchange the text as you like.

Comment: Thank you! And how I can get the backfround color of this?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean, the background colour of the button? Could you show me an example of one of the buttons (in terms of the actual html).

Comment: fI want to have a list of websites and for each one I want to find the "Add to card button" and find the color of it

Comment: Understood, I need to see an example of one of the html tags that you're trying to scrape from so I can understand the structure of it.

Comment: overview .add-to-cart-button:hover, .variant-overview .add-to-cart-button:hover {
    background-color: #b41733;

Comment: Could you please link the website and the desired button so I can take a look? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: https://www.inshoes.gr/andrikes-zones-andrikes-zones-dermatines-diplis-opseos-33000481-kamel-mavro

Answer (score 0):

To find all buttons on the page which contain the word ***card*** or the word ***bag*** you can clubup the conditions using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) within a *lambda* expression and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(., 'card')]") or driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(., 'bag')]"))
```